# Monorepo with npm workspaces - Lerna version fails when inter-package dependency is introduced for existing packages

Tags: npm, monorepo, lerna, npm-workspaces

I am working on a monorepo with 2 packages, say `child` and `parent`, initially **not** dependent on each other and already published to registry.

However, when I add inter-package dependency, `lerna version` command fails.

- npm workspaces was provided in root `package.json`
- useWorkspaces was provided in `lerna.json`

All was fine, till I decided to add package `parent` as dependency of package `child`.

`packages/child/package.json` was updated like so:

```
{
  "name": "child",
  "version": "0.1.13",
  "description": "this package is being updated to depend on parent",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "parent": "*"                                      // I added this
   }
}
```

I had updates to both `child` and `parent`. Lets say published versions of `parent` was `0.2.13` and `child` was `0.1.13` prior to update.

`npm install` and the symlinks worked.
Build was successful.

During version however, after prompting for version bump with conventional-commits, lerna attempts npm install command and fails due to package `parent` version `0.2.14` being not available in npm remote registry.

It will not be available, as this version is going to be published only now.

On version command (i am using conventional-commits),

- Lerna asked if `parent -> 0.2.14` and `child -> 0.1.14` was okay, it was..
- Lerna updated the `package.json` of package `child` to be as follows:

```
{
  "name": "child",
  "version": "0.1.14",                                               // lerna changed this
  "description": "this package is being updated to depend on parent",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "parent": "^0.2.14"                                             // lerna changed this
   }
}
```

- Lerna updated the `package.json` of package `parent` to be as follows:

```
{
  "name": "parent",
  "version": "0.2.14",                                               // lerna changed this
  "description": "this package will be dependency of child",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
}
```

- Lerna tried to do `npm install` on both `child` and `parent` packages

This fails with reason being package `parent` version `0.2.14` is not yet available to install, since its just going to be published now.

I followed this https://lerna.js.org/docs/getting-started.
It says

> The "header": "*" and "footer": "*" tell Lerna to link the contents of the header and footer as if they were published to the registry.

I was expecting the `lerna version` command to work and create new version commit and tag as it was doing before I added inter-package dependencies using "*".

Should I be publishing `parent` first with new version `0.2.14` and then update `child` to point to this ?
If that is the case, should I always publish `parent` first whenever there are breaking changes. ?

What is the right way to do this ?

PS: Looks like it fails here: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/main/commands/version/index.js#L634

Should I just remove `package-lock.json` from root ?

Comment: Try to add `"npmClient": "yarn"` to your `lerna.json` file

Comment: @NirG, but we use `npm`...

Comment: This also happens every time there is an update to `parent`. `lerna version` fails at `package-lock` update stage saying latest `parent` is not available in registry

Comment: the problem is that `npm` still has a long way to go to work nicely with workspaces, for example this [RFC - npm run-series && npm run-parallel](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/190) is open since 2020 and `npm` doesn't handle well dependent packages, you often have to manually tell it what the pkg build order is `npm run build --workspace=b --workspace=a`, all of these problems led me to switch to [pnpm `workspace:*`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) which is awesome and yarn also supports it. New Lerna and [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) also support `workspace:*`

Comment: We have the same issue. It looks like this is a NPM issue (ticket [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5967) ) Some people said reverting to NPM 8 helped - in my case it didn't.